# R logistic regression - erro message

Tags: r

I have a dataset to perform glm function as below, but it shows an error message:

Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1

```
'data.frame':   189 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ class      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ age        : int  3 5 4 5 3 3 5 4 3 5 ...
 $ menopause  : int  3 1 3 1 3 3 2 1 3 2 ...
 $ tumor-size : int  4 3 5 4 4 1 2 5 6 6 ...
 $ inv-nodes  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ node-capes : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ deg-malig  : int  2 2 2 1 2 3 1 3 3 1 ...
 $ breast     : int  2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ breast-quad: int  5 3 2 2 3 1 5 5 3 2 ...
 $ irradiat   : int  5 3 2 2 3 1 5 5 3 2 ...
```

Comment: I don’t see a glm call.

Comment: What's your y variable?

Answer (score 0):

This question ia already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546658/logistic-regression-on-factor-error-in-evalfamilyinitialize-y-values-must)

Try `as.factor()` for your dependent variable. In logistic regression you need to have dependent variable in binary form. Which, perhaps, is not declared in R yet.